# Email Blast plugin for Thunderbird

Tags: html-email, thunderbird, email-client

I've had a look in the Thunderbird plugins for an addon which will work as an Email Blast application to send out bulk mailers but found none. I was wondering if anyone knows of one or if none exist, I'm planting a seed! :)

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 0):

James,

I suggest you sign up with an Email Service Provider instead of using a plug in. There are many providers with free programs. You should have no problem sending a few hundred emails per month for free. If you need more than that, it will only cost a few dollars.

Plus you will get all kinds of nifty tracking!